# No me reconoce los plugins en netbeans 12.3

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, spring-boot, maven

estes es el problema que se registra, cada vez que reinicio el sistema me muestra que falta un plugins diferente, pero los tengo registrado en el Pom. Le agradezco me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema, ya que soy muy nuevo en esta area.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project ejemplo: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\hp\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ejemplo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

Este es mi Pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.12
 

com.example
ejemplo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
ejemplo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>1.8</java.version>

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.12</version>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>  
</build>
```

Comment: Hola Franklin, no me parece que sea problema de carga de plugins, sino de la ejecución de las pruebas, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar como texto el código de estas?.

Comment: Hola Marce, Estoy haciendo la conexión con la base de datos, y me da ese error. Este es el código para conectarme a la base de datos: server.contextPath=/ejemplo
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ejemplo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=""
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver